# Updating Column values comma seperatedly and Retieving

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a Table called User_TB and It contains column called Previous_Id, Previous_Id Going to hold hold all previous id's of that User he worked for Locations. Is it Possible to store values in such way, and if yes then Please help me with solution ..

Thanks

Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_TB](
[User_Id] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
[User_FullName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[User_Address] [varchar](150) NULL,
[User_Gender] [varchar](10) NULL,
[User_Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
[User_Password] [varchar](50) NULL,
[User_AccStatus] [int] NULL,
[User_Branch] [varchar](50) NULL,
[User_TeamLeader] [varchar](50) NULL,
[User_Department] [varchar](50) NULL,
[User_Position] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Previous_Id] [varchar](MAX) NULL
```

)

and Previous_Id column may hold values like : [LH-10,SQ-12]

and how to retrieve them in asp .net using any string variable.

right now my query is : 
Consider a one value is present in that column

```
Declare 
@User_Id varchar(20);
Update User_TB set User_Id=@User_Id where User_Id = @old_User_Id;
```

Comment: From where do you get the values for `Previous_Id`?

Comment: from my asp .net form

Comment: so you need to update this in your table. try this for update `Update User_TB set [Previous_Id]=@Previous_Id where User_Id = @User_Id;`

Comment: yes i have did this but i want old values and new values that comes through my asp .net form, i need them for further use

Comment: use `sqlparameter` with `sqlcommand` and pass the values from your form

Comment: let me explain you, suppose there is value in that column [SS-1] this value is already in that column, and now again i got value for that column is [MM-1] so after update i want values in that column like this  : [SS-1,MM-1]

Comment: use `Update User_TB set [Previous_Id]=[Previous_Id] + ',' + @Previous_Id where User_Id = @User_Id;`. if you need to get the value back to application, use `output inserted.Previous_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't already know the number of previous IDs, you will need to create a new table. You could call it Previous_IDs, for example. It will have 2 columns, one being User_Id, the other Previous_Id. For each new "Previous_Id" of a user, you can add a row in the table. You can then retrieve all these IDs with a query like

```
SELECT * from [dbo].[User_TB]
INNER JOIN Previous_Id
ON [dbo].[User_TB].User_Id = Previous_Id.user_id
WHERE User_Id = [ID of the user you want]
```

That may seem like a lot of work for a tiny thing, but it's the proper way I've been taught.

Comment: isn't it possible through User_TB instead of using another table. Actually i have done that already i.e. by using another table.

Comment: Not that I, or everyone who taught me about database-handling, know about.
The closest thing I can think about would be to have a varchar(255) field in which you enter a user's previous IDs, separated by commas. But it's not easy to read with a query and limited.